# Conditionally call relationship if model returns not null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have the following Eloquent query:

```
$presupuesto = Departamento::where([
        ['fk_presupuesto', '=', $request['periodo']],
        ['fk_programa', '=', $request['programa']['id_catalogo']],
        ['fk_departamento', '=', $request['departamento']['id_catalogo']],
    ])
        ->with([
            'bienes' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->select([
                    'fk_departamento',
                    'costo_total'
                ])->where([
                   ['fk_presupuesto', '=', $request['periodo']]
                ]);
            }
        ])
        ->first();
```

Query works great... when the where condition returns not null, otherwise Laravel yells at me with a Server Error, which I guess is because is calling the `with` on a null object.

##### Response from Laravel

[image: Response from Laravel]

How to check if the model returns not null? Or can I move the whole relationship with constraints to a `load` method?

Comment: `where` does not return `null`, it always return a `Builder`, that is why you can chain `->with(...)->first()`. Show us the error please

Comment: Well, yes, I'm aware the `where` does not return null until the query is executed, but the logic remains. I get a 500 Server Error.

Comment: Since `->with()` executes a subquery, you can do `$presupuesto = Departamento::where(...)->first();`, then `if ($presupuesto) { $presupuesto->load('bienes', function ($query) use ($request) { ... });` and it will be just as efficient, but you shouldn't need to. Matias is correct; `->with()` and `->where()` don't return `null`. Also, a `500 Server Error` is not helpful; please enable debugging and check `storage/logs/laravel.log` to see the actual error, including file, line, and message.

Comment: Right! I keep forgetting Laravel logs these kind of errors. Thanks for the reminder! And alas! Its not the query throwing the error, instead is the `toArray()` method I call when I return the answer :facepalm: Thanks to all for wasting a couple minutes helping me out.

Comment: Hey, it happens, no worries  glad to hear it's working now. That being said, I'd recommend deleting this question, as syntax errors, or local errors like these tend to attract downvotes and/or closed questions. Cheers. (or a self-answer is ok; probably won't get any votes, but all good)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it is not the `with()` relationship call giving the error, instead, reading the log (thanks Tim Lewis for the heads-up), it turns out to be how I return the final response, here's the error:

[2023-05-12 13:48:22] local.ERROR: Call to a member function toArray() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function toArray() on null

The query returns null and I'm trying to return a null->toArray().